# Display element only if target is specified id

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a few sections in my HTML with links that correspond to other sections like so:

```
<section class="sections" id="foo">
    <p>Foo Section</p>
    <img src="foo_image.jpg" />
    <a href="#blah">Go to blah</a>
</section>​
<section class="sections" id="blah">
    <p>Blah Section</p>
    <img src="blah_image.jpg" />
    <a href="#foo">Go to foo</a>
</section>
```

I'm currently using the following CSS to display only the targeted sections:

```
section {
    opacity: 0; 
    height: 0;
}

section:target {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

This works. The problem is that I need the user to see the first section to access the links in the other sections and this currently makes all sections un-viewable from the start.

Is there a way to only display an element if a section target is equal to a specified id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use jQuery as your tag suggests, it will be easier to set the section to show for the first time, and to remove it thereafter:

EDIT: Change to JS and HTML to help solve issue of ability to use hashes when present

HTML:

```
<section class="sections" id="foo">
    <p>Foo Section</p>
    <img src="foo_image.jpg" />
    <a href="#blah">Go to blah</a>
</section>
<section class="sections" id="blah">
    <p>Blah Section</p>
    <img src="blah_image.jpg" />
    <a href="#foo">Go to foo</a>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    opacity: 0; 
    height: 0;
}

section:target, .show{
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

jQuery:

```
if(!window.location.hash.length)
{
    $("#foo").addClass("show").find("a").on("click", function(){
        $(this).off("click").closest(".sections").removeClass("show");
    });
}
```

Alternative:
Forgot to mention you could always just do:

```
if(!window.location.hash.length)
{
   window.location.hash = "foo";
}
```

Comment: On second thought, this doesn't 100% solve my problem, as when I go to a specific link (ie /myurl#blah), the #foo section is still visible. Do you know if there's a way to query what the target is in the URL and display elements based on that target?

Comment: You can look at window.location.hash (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) and the onhashchange event

Answer (score 0):

I think the class name is sections, in that case add an id rule also which is more specific as such can override the rules specified by the class rule

```
.sections{
    opacity: 0; 
    height: 0;
}

.sections:target, #foo{
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with this, is that I want the first section (foo in this case) to become unviewable again once the other sections are reached. This makes the foo section viewable at all times. I've added a jquery function that hides the element once a button is clicked, but when I go to a url that specifies the target (ie /myurl#blah) the first #foo section is still visible, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a bit your HTML, but here's how I done it, used jquery to hide the other section/s.You can change the event with `.click` if you want the user to click on second section.

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#foo">Click here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blah">Click here</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<section class="hidden" id="foo">
    <p>Foo Section</p>
    <img src="foo_image.jpg" />
    <a href="#blah">Go to blah</a>
</section>​

<section class="hidden" id="blah">
    <p>Blah Section</p>
    <img src="blah_image.jpg" />
    <a href="#foo">Go to foo</a>
</section>
```

CSS: `.hidden{display:none}`

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu li a").mouseover(function(){
        $(".hidden").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    });
    /* Show the first div by default */
    $(".hidden:first").show();
});
```

Here's a fiddle: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jj4fa2wc/)